# Hide license expire date into BD field

Tags: spring, postgresql

I'm facing a situation where I'm going to install a web application (Java8 + Spring MVC + Spring JDBC) and the database (PostgreSQL 9.5) in the server of a client.

I need to manage the client license expire date and the server doesn't have access to internet, so I need to find some way to store that date into de DB but without the chance for the client to change it (they have admin privileges for the app and the DB).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Trust the client and rely on non-technical means of enforcement. Anything else is doomed to fail. If you really insist on doing it, compile it into your app source code.

Answer (score -1):

Finally we decide to encode the license date with a public-private key, so the date is almost non breakable.